# ¿Actualizar mapa Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, map, leaflet

Estoy desarrollando el modulo de un sistema, el cual recoge de la base de datos la latitud y longitud, las tranfiero a un archivo .js en donde con JQUERY los muestro en inputs, de la siguiente manera.

```
$("#lat").val($.trim(data[0].latitud))
$("#long").val($.trim(data[0].longitud))
```

en la vista .php tengo un`<span>` el cual almacena los valores de los 2 input, se lo asigno en una funcion cada que busco en la base de datos, entonces este cada que hay una busqueda cambia de valor, hasta aqui funciona bien.

```
var cootext=document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = $.trim(data[0].latitud)+","+$.trim(data[0].longitud);
```

seguido de esto llamo a la funcion enviandole la coordenada en texto, `cmap(cootext)`
Mi función esta así:

```
function cmap(cootext){
    let map = L.map('map').fitWorld();
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
      let coords = cootext.split(",");
      console.log(coords)
      L.marker(coords).addTo(map)
      map.flyTo(coords, 18);
}
```

El problema es que solo funciona con la primera búsqueda, el mapa se posiciona en los valores que recibe del `<span>`, pero al hacer otra búsqueda el `<span>` cambia su valor pero el mapa no se mueve a mostrar el nuevo marcador.

Espero puedan Ayudarme Gracias!

Comment: ¿Que te muestra en consola?, creo que necesitas limpiar el layer para poner un nuevo marcador

Comment: en consola no me muestra errores, de que manera limpiaria el layer? Probe vaciando el <div id="map"> con .empty() , y con innerHTML pero no tuve exito.

Comment: Agrega ```if (map != null) {map._leaflet_id = null;}```, despues de declarar la variable map